# Can JavaScript Azure webjobs trigger based on additions to a storage blob?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

There are lots of examples using C# to trigger a webjob based on updated to a blob store (using C# method argument types and annotations). Is equivalent functionality available for JS webjobs?

The related azure-functions seem to allow this via a function.json file, but there doesn't seem to be anything for node webjobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Please see the **BlobTrigger-Node** template that is available in the Functions portal. Enter your container name, and your Node function will be invoked when new blobs are added to the container:

```
module.exports = function (context, myBlob) {
    context.log('Node.js blob trigger function processed blob:', myBlob);
    context.done();
};
```

You can also run the Functions runtime in a **regular Continuous WebJob** if you wish. There is a sample showing how to do this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script-samples/tree/master/WebJobScript).

Comment: Had another answer but it is aligned with this. Essentially, please consider using Azure Functions as like Mathew demonstrates above, it extends the WebJobs capabilities to other languages, including JS.